# lines drawn in a plane

Tags: geometry

Seventeen lines drawn in a plane, with no three concurrent and no two parallel divide the plane into closed regions and open regions. What is the number of closed regions?

I figured out the number of regions is 154 but I am not able to figure out the number of closed regions.

Comment: How did you figure out the number of regions?

Comment: by using the formula 1/2 (n2 + n + 2)

Comment: It might be easier to find the number of open regions - don't 17 lines, going off to infinity, make 34 non-closed regions?

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this question would be 120. As you can see from a chart
number of lines   0 1 2 3 4 5
number of closed  0 0 0 1 3 6

The formula to find the number of closed should be: n-2(n-1)/2
If we input 17 then, 15*16/2 is equal to 120.